# openpyxl how to switch default sheet

Tags: xlsx, openpyxl

My xlsx file has 5 sheets,
I can change fourth sheet content,
after change,
I save to a new file.

But when I open the new file,
I need manual to select the fourth sheet.

How can I change the default sheet to fourth sheet?

Thanks!

---

update

It`s work!
Thank you very much.
But still a little question,

[first and fourth sheet both select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29Nj.jpg)

I want this [only fourth sheet select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INKjl.jpg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply set `wb.active` to the index of the sheet, eg. `wb.active = 3` for the fourth sheet.

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same problem as Kobe with [multiple sheets selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29Nj.jpg) when manually opening the file after only setting `wb.active` and saving.

For me the workaround was explicitly setting the `tabSelected` property of every sheet in the workbook in addition to setting the active worksheet. Here is a minimal example:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_file.xlsx')

workbook.active = 2 # making the third sheet active

for sheet in workbook:
    if sheet.title == 'your_sheet_name':
        sheet.sheet_view.tabSelected = True
    else:
        sheet.sheet_view.tabSelected = False

workbook.save('your_file.xlsx')
```

With this only one sheet is selected after you manually open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `wb.active` and `tabSelected` on each sheet. Only setting `wb.active` can result in artifacts, as mentioned in the question and @Chillie's answer.

Specifically, I am loading an Excel workbook as template and editing it. The black-green highlighting artifact will be on the sheet I had open when I saved the template in Excel (here "Pro FW Δ"). You won't see any artifacts if the sheet you set as active was already your last-opened one.

[image]

I made a function which correctly sets the active sheet without artifacts by setting `tabSelected`:

```py
def make_sheet_active(wb: openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook, main_sheet_name: str):
    wb.active = wb[main_sheet_name]
    for ws in wb:
        ws.views.sheetView[0].tabSelected = ws.title == main_sheet_name
```

[image]

I used `openpyxl==3.0.10`.